# I am confused with XMLHTTPREQUEST()

Tags: javascript

I know XmlHttpRequest is an object. But why do we create a new object when we use it's properties and methods? For example:

```
var xmlhttp = new xmlhttprequest();
```

we use xmlhttp.readystate or xmlhttp.status properties. why we can't use xmlhttprequest.readysate or xmlhttprequest.status directly.

And why do we use parenthesis () after this? It is not a function is it?

please help.

Comment: bcz readystate and status  are not static properties that u can use it directly by calling xmlhttprequest.readystate. those properties are part of the class xmlhttprequest as public so u have to instantiate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a constructor: more info here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/XMLHttpRequest

You can create your own to see how it works.

```
function Person(name) {
  this.name = name;
}

var me = new Person('Kirill'); //now you can access it via me.name
```

So here a person is initialized with the name - so is the `XMLHttpRequest`: it has to be initialized before you can work with it's properties

Answer (score 0):

Basically XMLHttpRequest object is an interface. As per [W3.org](https://www.w3.org/TR/2006/WD-XMLHttpRequest-20060405/)

> The XMLHttpRequest object is an interface exposed by a scripting
>   engine that allows scripts to perform HTTP client functionality, such
>   as submitting form data or loading data from a remove Web site.

If you check the typeof see what comes the result:

```js
console.log("XMLHttpRequest is a "+typeof XMLHttpRequest);

console.log("new XMLHttpRequest() is an "+typeof new XMLHttpRequest());
```

So when you use `new XMLHttpRequest()` that means you are creating an instance of `XMLHttpRequest` using `XMLHttpRequest()` constructor.